# Parameters in Enumerable.Where

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to search for all records which are null, or not null. I can do this that way (sample code):

```cs
public ICollection<Employees> SearchForPhoneNumberNull()
{
    return collection.Where(x => x.PhoneNumber == null);
}
```

```cs
public ICollection<Employees> SearchForPhoneNumberNotNull()
{
    return collection.Where(x => x.PhoneNumber != null);
}
```

Can i somehow connect these two methods, and for example send some variable that will decide is it `!=` or `==`?

Comment: Easiest way is to group the two statements in one method by checking a parameter to see if you'll use the first check or the second one.

Comment: Take a look at the [Logical exclusive OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, like this:

```
public ICollection<Employees> SearchForPhoneNumber(bool nullOnly)
{
    return collection.Where(x => nullOnly ? x.PhoneNumber == null : x.PhoneNumber != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool` argument to verify if the phone number should be `null` or not.

Also the `Where` method returns `IEnumerable`, there is no explicit converstion to `ICollection`, thus I changed the method's declaration

```
        public IEnumerable<Employees> SearchForPhoneNumber(bool isNull = true)
        {
            return collection.Where(x => isNull ? x.PhoneNumber == null : x.PhoneNumber != null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For single function to handle both null and non-null Phone Numbers, I would implement an extension function.

```cs
static class EmployeesExtensions
{
    public static ICollection<Employees> SearchForPhoneNumber(
        this ICollection<Employees> collection, 
        Func<Employees, bool> predicate)
    {
        return collection.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
}
```

There are a few important things to note here.

- Extension functions ***must*** be in a static class (i.e., `static class EmployeesExtensions`
- `this ICollection<Employees> collection`

  - Defines the type of object on which the extension function can be called.
  - `this` enables the function to be used as an extension function.
- `Func<Employees, bool> predicate`

  - Allows passing a lambda expression to the extension function.

    - Takes an Employees object as a parameter
    - Returns a `bool` (i.e., True/False).
  - Example: `e => e.PhoneNumber == null`
  - passed to `.Where()` by name, `predicate`
- `.ToList()` is needed to convert the `IEnumerable<Employees>` to `ICollection<Employees>`. However, this forces the evaluation of the LINQ expression tree that you are building. So, rather than returning a composable expression tree, it returns the actual `Employees` objects.

So, now that we have an extension method, we can use it in a program.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employees = CreateEmployeesCollection();

        Console.WriteLine("Employees with Phone Number");

        foreach (var e in employees.SearchForPhoneNumber(
            e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PhoneNumber)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {e.Id}; Name: {e.Name}; Phone: {e.PhoneNumber}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Employees with No Phone Number");

        foreach (var e in employees.SearchForPhoneNumber(
            e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PhoneNumber)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {e.Id}; Name: {e.Name}; Phone: null");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Employees with Phone Number in 312 Area Code");

        foreach (var e in employees.SearchForPhoneNumber(
            e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PhoneNumber)
            && e.PhoneNumber.StartsWith("312")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {e.Id}; Name: {e.Name}; Phone: {e.PhoneNumber}");
        }
    }

    private static ICollection<Employees> CreateEmployeesCollection()
    {
        var employees = new Collection<Employees>();

        employees.Add(new Employees { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", PhoneNumber = null });
        employees.Add(new Employees { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", PhoneNumber = "212-555-1212" });
        employees.Add(new Employees { Id = 3, Name = "Mike Smith", PhoneNumber = "312-555-1213" });
        employees.Add(new Employees { Id = 4, Name = "Mary Smith", PhoneNumber = "312-555-1214" });
        employees.Add(new Employees { Id = 5, Name = "Bob Jones", PhoneNumber = "214-555-1215" });
        employees.Add(new Employees { Id = 5, Name = "Beth Jones", PhoneNumber = null });

        return employees;
    }
}
```

Oh, also, for this example, I assumed the following definition of the Employees class

```cs
// File: Employees.cs
class Employees
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```